# Mounting Raw Disk Image File in Nautilus

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10.  As part of SD card creation, I have a script that successfully creates a raw disk image file, correctly formatted with an ext2 file system. I have built SD cards from the raw disk image file with dd.

Now, I'd like to mount it and browse the files using Nautilus.

I know I can use **mount -o,loop** to mount it to a mount point. I would like to get it mounted by gnome to an automatically created /media/xxx mount point. I have used **partprobe /dev/loopn** to get the file noticed. It appears in my Places menu and if I select it from there, nautilus opens the disk, just fine.

What I would like to do is get my script to kick nautilus so its file browser window opens the image file's root without having to select it from the Places menu.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use gvfs-mount.

#### List mountable devices

```
gvfs-mount -li
```

#### Mount device file found above from label

```
gvfs-mount -d /dev/sdaX
```

Nautilus uses the same underlying library (gvfs)

After that you can use

```
nautilus /media/LABEL
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know the path to the directory you can use `gnome-open` like:

```
gnome-open /media/xxx
```

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, while the volume label appears in the Places menu, it is not yet mounted anywhere.  So there is nothing in the /media directory, yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gnome-disk-image-mounter` (probably with option `--writable`) to mount an image using Gnome, which itself will be available by *Nautilus*.

If you want a graphical application like Nautilus to browse the files, why do you not configure it to mount images by itself?
With '*right-click|Properties|Open With*' you can just use `gnome-disk-image-mounter` to do the task you want, including opening the folder.
See my [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407888/gnome-files-nautilus-context-menu-open-with-application-list) to open the image writeable.